Run flutter web app on Chrome on iOS machine
I have a Flutter app that I have compiled to run on Chrome on a Windows machine. I have tried to get it to run on Chrome on an iOS machine but it doesn't work.
This is what the user sees when typing in the URL.

It works fine for me when I run it in a Chrome browser on a Windows machine and an Android phone. I need it to run on any browser on an iOS machine and an iPhone.
I have looked for answers on what I need to do to get this to work on iOS but have not found any good answers. Most tell me to start with an iOS device.
How must I get this to run on iOS and Chrome or any browser?
This is my index.html code but I don't know if this helps:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>flutter_notification_test</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
    <!--Update with yours config-->
      const firebase config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDBIaLXzl5tF2QNTN58s2iPDI--GLr7bqo",
      authDomain: "deal-diligence-5de73.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "deal-diligence-5de73",
      storageBucket: "deal-diligence-5de73.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "394692266013",
      databaseURL: "https://deal-diligence-5de73-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
      appId: "1:394692266013:web:0b5da830c03cc9d1a51ef4",
    };
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
</script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script>
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register("/firebase-messaging-sw.js");
        });
      }
</script>
</body>
</html>

Thanks for your help
